# String vs Object#toString

Tags: java, coding-style, api-design

Is there a case where you'd have a parameter of type `Object` for a method and internally call `toString()` as opposed to having a `String` parameter and having the user of the method handle string-conversion?

An example method being `log(Object)` vs `log(String)`
The latter is less ambiguous, and more flexible, but may introduce duplicate occurances of `log(object.toString())`.

Is there some form of javadoc convention that could be used to explicitly denote that the `Object` variant of the method will make use of `Object#toString` - to avoid a consumer of the method forgetting to override `toString`?

Comment: I'm not referring to any library, it was an example.

Answer (score 1):

In the majority of cases `method(String)` is better than `method(Object)` as it is more explicit, it clearly communicates the contract of your method - the caller knows you expect a `String` rather than an `Object`, on which you will call `toString()`.

However, if you implement e.g. a logging library with methods such as `info(String format, Object arg)`, it is might be better to use an `Object`. The logging library does not care whether the argument is a `String`, `Long`, `Integer`, etc. and instead of having hundreds of overloaded methods it is better to define just one method that takes an `Object`.

Answer (score -1):

"You can use toString() on an object to get the string representation of that object.

```
// Java program to illustrate 
// working of toString() method 
class Best_Friend { 
    String name; 
    int age; 
    String college; 
    String course; 
    String address; 
    Best_Friend 
    (String name, int age, String college, String course, String address) 
    { 
        this.name = name; 
        this.age = age; 
        this.college = college; 
        this.course = course; 
        this.address = address; 
    } 
public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Best_Friend b =  
        new Best_Friend("Gulpreet Kaur", 21, "BIT MESRA", "M.TECH", "Kiriburu"); 
        System.out.println(b); 
        System.out.println(b.toString()); 
    } 
}
```

The Result:

```
Output: Best_Friend@232204a1
```

"

- Work cited from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-tostring-method-in-java/
- Author: Bishal Kumar Dubey

Comment: I would sugggest official java documentation links instead, they are usually better mantained.

Comment: Good comment - You are right, I should have done that instead.